What can we say about the generators of a C* -operator algebra and the C*-algebra it spans?
If given a finite set of unitary matrices $G=\{U_i\}_i^n$ acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ that fulfill $\sum_G U_i U_i^\dagger= Id$ and we look at the algebra this set spans $\mathfrak{U}$, I read that this algebra was a $C^*$-algebra that was also a so-called Cuntz algebra $O_n$.
Now, what properties does $G$ and the elements therein need to fulfill such that $\mathfrak{U}$ can be identified with the algebra of bounded operators $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$?
I know that with the help of the Gelfand-Naimark theorem we can find a $^*$-isomorphism to a norm-closed adjoint closed subalgebra of $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$, but I am not sure if this was enough, since it is only a subalgebra of it. Could this still be utilized?
Could you alternatively refer me to a resource that may answer this questions?
I would be very glad for your help, thank you in advance.

Read the original paper here about Cuntz algebra- https://projecteuclid.org/journalArticle/Download?urlId=cmp%2F1103901288

You might need to look carefully about  C*-algebras generated by operators acting on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. In this case, $\mathfrak{U}$ is such a C$^*$-algebra. Indeed, $\mathfrak{U}$ is obtained by taking all intersections of $C^*$-subalgebras containing $U_1, U_2, \dotsc, U_n$ (and of-course their adjoints). In a more precise manner, $\mathfrak{U}$ is the norm closure of all polynomials of elements in $G$ and $G^*$ where $G^*=\lbrace T^*: T \in G \rbrace$. By Gelfand-Naimark-Siegel Theorem, $\mathfrak{U}$ is isometrically $*$-isomorphic to a subalgebra of some $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ for some Hilbert space $\mathcal{K}$. In this case, it is superfluous since you are already starting with $C^*$-algebra $B(\mathcal{H})$.
If $\mathfrak{U}$ is generated by commuting normal matrices $U_1, \dotsc, U_n$ (in particular unitary), $\mathfrak{U}$ is a commutative $C^*$-algebra and hence, $\mathfrak{U}$ cannot be the whole of $B(\mathcal{H})$.

And when is this intersection equal $\mathfrak{B}(\mathcal{H})$? What properties must $G$ fulfill that this is given? What is the minimum cardinality in this case f.e.?

It is not possible since $\mathfrak{U}$ consists of normal matrices and so, $\mathfrak{U}$ cannot be $B(\mathcal{H})$.

Thank you already for this answer. Sorry for my misunderstanding, but why would it be a commutative algebra? A commutative algebra is if
$\forall U_i, U_j : U_i U_j=U_j_U_i$
which would not be the case here.
Do you have some paper that deals with generators of these algebras on this level?

@relativeentropy about commutativity : If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are commuting normal operators then $N_1^N_2=N_2N_1^$. This is called doubly commutativity condition.

But $U_i$ and $U_j$ are not commuting operators in my example. They are of course normal, but a set of normal operators is not usually automatically commuting, right?

@relativeentropy my bad!

No problem, we are here to think together! So, what is your view on the operators then?
Or can you refer me to a book that deals with this? I find it really hard to find something that just deals with these basic questions like "what does a generator has to look like for this algebra". I just find some weird very specific papers that don't help me continue.
I want some book that deals with generators and the usual bounded operator algebra on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. Nothing completely exotic or super high level.
